# Change the footer in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, styles, web-deployment, footer

How can I edit the footer in WordPress version 5.3.1?

footer.php:

```
do_action('creativ_musicial_action_before_footer' );

/**    
  * Hooked - creativ_musician_footer_top_section -10      
  * Hooked - creativ_musician_footer_section -20      
  */

do_action( 'creativ_musician_action_footer' );

 /**      
 * Hooked - creativ_musician_footer_end.        
 */

do_action( 'creativ_musician_action_after_footer' );

<p>Test</p>    

wp_footer(); ?>

</body>

</html>
```

I can not change the footer text in the GUI. This is the footer:

[image: footer]

Which `php` file is the right one, and how can I change it?

[image: footer.php]

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please add code as text, not screenshots.  This enables people to quickly copy/paste code into their editors in order to efficiently help you out. Also, it can be difficult to read code in images, depending on resolution, color, font size, and the device they are working from. For instance, I'm using a mobile phone right now, which typically render images to small to read text.  Additionally, SO's sister site https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ is dedicated to questions specific to WordPress, like this one. SO is more suited for questions about specific code. All the Best.

Comment: I am voting to close this for now, and if it can be edited to contain code in text format, I will withdraw my vote.

Answer (score 1):

You need to delete, or comment out, the line calling the function, `creativ_musician_action_footer`.

```
/* do_action( 'creativ_musician_action_footer' ); */
```

Optionally, you can add your own HTML in its place, if you want to add a custom footer of your own.

**OR**

You can open the `functions.php` and edit the function `creativ_musician_action_footer` so it has the text that you want.

However, neither of those are a great solution, because when you update the theme, your changes may be lost.

**Instead**, you should create a child theme and edit a copy of the footer file from your child's theme folder. By doing this your changes will be resilient through updates.  There are plenty of tutorials on child themes, and it's fairly easy to do.
Here is the [WordPress codex on child themes](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/).

Essentially, in your child-theme folder, you'll create a *new* `style.css`, and a *new* `functions.php`, and *copy* over the orig `footer.php` file.  Your child `footer.php` will override the version in the orig/parent's theme folder, so you need to *copy* the orig `footer.php` to your new child theme folder, then *edit* this copy to meet your needs.  You'll probably also want to copy over the orig theme screenshot, or create a new one.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will try it with the children theme.

Comment: @Pacotestversion, Glad to help. Please edit your post to add code in text format. As it stands, SO may delete your post. It was in the review cue for closing when I revived it. It is fair to other users & anyone who spent time on it, if you 1) edit to bring it up to SO standards. 2) upvote any answers and comments you found helpful 3) click the checkmark on one, if any, that you feel helped the most. This *builds your reputation*, rewards helpers with points, & helps guide future visitors with similar problems to quickly find answers to theirs. Also, it's good practice for next time!